# Каким образом поисковик проверяет уникальность текста на сайте?

Tags: seo, поисковая-оптимизация

Здравствуйте.

У меня такой вопрос. Как поисковик определяет какой сайт первым добавил статью и какому сайту даст "балы" при ранжировании за уникальность, если она появилась одновременно на разных сайтах?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

[Как подтвердить авторство?](http://wildblog.ru/2012/05/kak-podtverdit-avtorstvo-tekstov-dlya-yandeksa-i-google-vse-prosto/)

Есть замечательный ресурс, в котором описано всё, что касается уникальности и авторства текста, и какими критериями руководствуются поисковики, для его присвоения.

Comment: получается, если поисковик обойдет сайт конкурента раньше и увидит там статью которую я разместил за час например до него, то после обхода моего сайта - он посчитает мою статью не уникальной?

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6083347?hl=ru&visit_id=1-636599976826018124-2307456418&rd=1 В результатах Веб-поиска больше не поддерживается разметка информации об авторстве.